# Clarification on a probability problem

Tags: probability

The students of CS 245 “Reasoning about Certainty” are
taking a midterm. The midterm lasts for a maximum of $120$ minutes but if we pick a random student, the expected time taken by the student is only $60$ minutes.

Let $T$ be the time taken by the student.

**What’s the largest value var(T) can take and what’s the corresponding PMF?**

I know the answer is:

" Let $P(T = 0) = 1/2$ and $P(T = 120) = 1/2$, then $var(T) = 60^2 = 3600$."

But I am wondering how the answer became that.

How is $P(T=0)=0.5$ and $P(T=120)= 0.5$?

I understand that the $var(T) = E[(T - E[T])^2]$ but I can't understand how all the numbers fit in the formula.

Could someone maybe expand on the answer given?

Comment: The largest possible variation in times will be when half the students are at one extreme and the other half at the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest variation will occur when the students times are spread fartherest apart from the mean time (whatever it is); that is some are at one extreme and the rest at the other.

Let the proportion of students taking the maximum time available be $p\in(0;1)$, such that: $$\mathsf P(T=120) = p, \mathsf P(T=0)=1-p$$

The variance is thus: $\mathsf {Var}(T) = 120^2p - (120p)^2$

There will be a local critical point (ie minimum/maximum/inflection) when the derivative is zero.   A quick inspection shows it shall be a maximum; and we find the value to be:

$$0 = 120^2(1-2p) \\ p= \tfrac 12$$

Which means the largest possible variance in time will occur when exactly half of the students make use of the full time available, and the other half immediately quit (taking no time to do the exam).

$$\mathsf {Var}(T) = 3600$$